# htaccess Rewrite rule issue for css with '/'

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have Rewrite rule as below.

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^inner-subcategory-([0-9]+)$ /inner.php?subcat_id=$1
```

This rule is working fine. The URL will be like this

```
    http://www/abc.com/inner-subcategory-10
```

But if I am using '/' instead of '-', CSS can not be applied.
This means, I want a URL like `http://www/abc.com/inner/subcategory/10`

Comment: What do you mean by "CSS cannot be applied"?

Comment: means page is broken... Can u just help how can i use '/' instead of '-' ?

Comment: Just replace `-` by `/`. If CSS breaks by this change, this is a different issue.

Comment: yes, its issue of relative urls. But now I cant change it to absolue url everywhere.. can u pls help ?

Comment: You must provide enough details about your CSS URLs, otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.simpleLens.css">

Comment: I have used css like this , but if i use <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/css/jquery.simpleLens.css">, then its working.. But cant change it now, because I have to change in css, js and image path.

Comment: Use `<base>` tag in your pages.

Answer (score 0):

To use slashes instead of hyphens, replace `-` by `/`

```
RewriteRule ^inner/subcategory/([0-9]+)$ /inner.php?subcat_id=$1
```

---

The second part, rewriting the `css` folder, depends on the requested URL. When the main page is requested as `/inner/subcategory/5`, then the relative CSS URL will be requested as `/inner/subcategory/css/jquery.simpleLens.css`. This means, you must add another `RewriteRule` and rewrite the css folder to an absolute URL

```
RewriteRule ^inner/subcategory/(css/.+)$ /$1 [L]
```

Same goes for Javascript files or images.